# Center Raised Button in tabbar iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I was trying to achieve this:
[image: Centered Raised TabBar]
After searching on the internet I found this [idev-recipes/RaisedCenterTabBar](https://github.com/boctor/idev-recipes/tree/master/RaisedCenterTabBar)
which is something I tried working with
But I don't know why it is not showing the buttons or this is not the way I'm making my app.
 My questions is that is there any way of doing it like I create a `tabBarController` in `.xib` and then `ctrl+drag` it to different view controllers. And then apply the raised code to the center button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found [this library](https://github.com/singer1026/IrregularTabbarCustom) which is doing exactly as I wanted. It have created a `tabbarcontroller` and then `ctrl+drag` it to different view controller. And than in the library I downloaded I gave `LCTabBarController` to my tabbar and changed the setting in other files, changed icons and achieved it successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You can't CTRL-DRAG between xib and storyboard.There're two solution:

1.CTRL-DRAG actions from xib and make jumping in codes.

2.Build that tool bar taht contains in a view controller in storyboard.(You can't add only view in storyboard)